# IBtransaction and Firebird for a multi-user program

Tags: delphi, firebird

I have a multiuser delphi program which has Firebird database behind it.

And I want 2 user can insert 2 records same time but with given automated number for a field.

On the other hand I am not sure Firebird is eligible for this without one use commit and close the table. And the other one refreshing it...

I heard bad things about commitretaining and I don't now what to do now. Like:

- Which transaction setting is best for me?
- Wait or No-wait if I have to use commitretaining how can I do that safely?

Comment: Firebird can handle concurrent transaction without a problem (its whole architecture is built for concurrency), unless you specifically use some of its more esoteric features like table reservation.

Answer (score 2):

Use GENERATORS. With GENERATORS you get always unique numbers. It doesn't matter how many transactions are active, they live outside the transaction control.

See [Firebird Generator Guide](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/generatorguide/firebird-generator-guide.html#generatorguide-basics)

Comment: On the other hand how can I handle delete? You know generators continue to count even if some of the datas are deleted. Can I change the last generator value programmatically?

Comment: Yes, you can set the generator as well: 
SET GENERATOR generator-name TO <new-value> 
http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-set-generator.html

Comment: You shouldn't use `SET GENERATOR` to reset a generator because you deleted something, that might introduce problems(eg two connections at the same time reset the value and then retrieve an incremented value, they might both end up with the same value). Why does it matter if 'holes' exist in the numbering?